# access wamp server www directory through c# project

Tags: c#-4.0, wamp

I need to do the following:
save an image(screenshot) from the c# project to a directory, and display this image on a html/php page using wamp server.

Now I can do one of the following:
-save the image to wamp's www directory (in this case i need to know from the c# project where this directory is)
-save the image in the project's bin directory (in this case my html/php page needs to know where this project's bin directory is)
-save the image in some directory other than the 2 mentioned above (in this case both the project and wamp need to know where this directory is)

What is the most appropriate way of doing this, and how should I go about coding it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Allow the user to configure where the image should go. Use the xampp www location as the default.